# Image scrolling instead of pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, nopcommerce

I have a site that uses nopcommerce for it's back end and the featured products use a pagination to display on the home page. I am changing the site to better responsive design and would like to make the featured products scroll instead of a paginator. This is the code we currently use for the paginator, what is the best way to do this?

Code:

```
if(Model.Count > 5)
        {
            <div id="featuredproductspaginator">
                <span onclick="prevFeaturedProduct();" class="on">&lt;</span>
                <span onclick="nextFeaturedProduct();" class="on">&gt;</span>
            </div>
        }
```

Comment: you need to customize here, instead of 5 product load more product and remove paging and put productbox in ul li and give slider class and add slider script so this will works